# How do I get Docker to mount VM volumes on OSX

Tags: macos, docker

I apologize if this is better on serverfault or [ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), it's not immediately clear to me where this question belongs.

I'm currently running [docker for mac](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/docker.rb) and I have a pretty strong understanding of how to mount folders from my OSX host machine inside of running docker containers.  My understanding is that docker is achieving this by running a Linux VM and handling the mounting between the VM and the host machine.

What I want to do is mount folders from the VM inside of my running container.

I can sort of accomplish this by running docker from inside of docker:

```
docker run --privileged \
           -it \
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           ubuntu-docker-client@sha256:038874e2c9c663550c9ddb0c8eb814c88d8a264cd1a5bfb4305dec9282598094 \
           /bin/bash -c "docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh -c 'chroot /host && /bin/sh'"
```

This handles the problem by escaping the chroot jail from inside a running container through the use of privileged containers.

I was hoping to find a solution which was less invasive and allowed me to mount volumes from both the host machine (OSX) and the linux VM.

Comment: It seems like just running the command directly on the host would be easier...what's the use case for starting inside Docker?

Comment: By "on the host" I assume you mean "on the vm."  I have a use case where I want to distribute a container which needs access to part of the underlying VMs file system and my target includes developers running docker on mac.  Asking them to go through additional steps manually adds friction to the process and increases the failure rate and support burden